# Can Hibernate create separate table from same entity when row limit reached a threshold?

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

I'm really new to hibernate. But I was wondering is there a way to start a new table from the same entity when the original table has reached a certain amount of rows?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that?

Comment: @Kayaman I need a table where the id field doesn't exceed 255 because the server it is connecting cannot process the records correctly after id = 255

Comment: So you thought the best solution is to divide the data into tables of max 255 rows?

Comment: I'm open to ideas, that was the first idea I could think of

Comment: I suggest you fix the part that has the problem.

Comment: How do you plan to deal with non-unique ID's? I agree with @Kayaman, you should probably fix the real issue.